# simplest code to spill a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called table1 in mysql.  I want to output it all, each row on a separate line.  It has 4 columns, id,a,b,c.

Whats the shortest php code to just get it all out?  I'm up to here:

```
$a=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
$b=mysql_fetch_assoc($a);
```

...what next?

What if their are an unknown number of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a)){
  echo $row['id'].$row['a'].$row['b'].$row['c'].'<br />';
}
```

Update in relation to this questions comment:

```
$a=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a)){
  foreach($row as $value)
    echo $value;
  echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: what if there were an unknown number of columns?

Comment: do a foreach loop on the $row

Answer (score 2):

```
echo `mysql --html -e "SELECT * FROM database.table1"`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<?php
while($b = mysql_fetch_row($a)) {
    echo('<tr>');
    foreach($b as $str) {
        echo("<td>$str</td>");
    }
    echo('</tr>');
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: @David how about to get the *idea*, put some **efforts** and make it work? Or you're asking for charity?

Comment: @David: Replace  `foreach($row as $str)`  with  `foreach($b as $str)`

@Col.Shrapnel: The example code was wrong, no need for your tone.

Answer (score -1):

Prints the array recursively:

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
$b = mysql_fetch_array($a);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($b);
echo "</pre>";
```